# wget doesn't convert URLs properly when --convert-links is specified

Tags: wget

According to the man pages, when I specify `--convert-links` to wget:

> After the download is complete, convert the links in the document to make them suitable for local viewing [...]
>   Note that only at the end of the download can Wget know which links have been downloaded. Because of that, the work done by -k will be performed at the end of all the downloads.

Let's say I do something like `wget --convert-links http://stackoverflow.com`. This site is large enough that I may never complete downloading everything. In this case, will I never get my links converted over?

When I run this locally from `/tmp/wget`, I see a directory called `stackoverflow.com` with files like `index.html` and `tour.html`. But when I load up the index page and hover over the link for the tour, it takes me to `file:///tour.html`, instead of `file:///tmp/wget/stackoverflow.com/tour.html` (the actual file location).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only question seems to be:

> In this case, will I never get my links converted over?

I guess not.  You could try this with a partition limited in size and see what wget does when it runs out of space (or use the `--quota` option, presumably it will still convert with that).

I can understand why this is the strategy.  If this were done on the fly, then we would have to go through every document for every item that is downloaded.  Consider:

- A.html is downloaded.
- B.html is downloaded, now check A.html for links.
- C.html is downloaded, now check A.html and B.html for links.
- ...and so on.

Instead, presumably a manifest is kept and then at the end all documents are scanned *once*.  Of course, my on-the-fly method could be improved by keeping an index of all links, but I still think it will be orders of magnitude slower -- **and require orders of magnitude more frequent writing to disk.**  Instead of saving a file, then changing it once at the end, you would commonly be rewriting it dozens or hundreds of times.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed the same thing -- that you need the whole site to efficiently parse links. So there's no solution to this as far as using `wget` itself?

Comment: That line in the man page seems pretty definitive.  If I were going to implement an alternative, I'd have one to allow it to use intelligent guesses on-the-fly rather than wait to do it all decisively.  In the general case though, that would not be desirable.  You could suggest a feature to whoever maintains wget; it's mostly a matter of human resources.